# New to C++ Arrays having trouble outputting element of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include<array>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    array < array <int, 5 >, 3 > A1 = { 25, 4, 5, 26, 67, 22, 44, 89, 5, 7, 33, 49, 42, 34, 106 };
    cout << A1[3][1];
    cout << A1[2][2];
}
```

What am I missing to output that?

Also how many rows and how many columns does this have? 5 and 3 right?

Comment: There are 3 elements in the array: A1[0], A1[1] and A1[2]. There's no A1[3]. –

Comment: reading beyond the bounds of array `25, 4, 5, 26, 67,   22, 44, 89, 5, 7,    33, 49, 42, 34, 106 ` as you can see 3 rows (0, 1, 2) and 5 columns (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) in your code you are reading row forth (3) which causes crash